# find ALL shortest paths in 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path

I try to figure out how to find ALL shortest paths in my data strucutre, but trying it with a recursive approach failed so far. An example input looks like this: (s= start cell, e= end cell). I want to find all shortes ways from 's' to 'e' and store them in an ArrayList.

```
. . . . .
. s . . .
. . . . .
. . . e .
. . . . . 
. . . . .
```

the Cell class looks like this and represents one cell in the above matrix:

```
public class Cell {
    private int line;
    private int column;
    private char character;
    ...
    public Cell(int line, int column) {
        this.line = line;
        this.column = column;
    }

}
```

I also have a Field Class, which contains an ArrayList with all nodes in it, and the total number of columns and lines which represent the field (in the above case, columns=5, lines=6, and List contains all 30 Cells of the field).

```
public class Field {
    private List<Cell> cells;
    private int lines;
    private int columns;
    ...
    }
```

and what I tried so far was:

```
// starti= line-index of cell s, starj= column-index of cell s
// should create an ArrayList<Cell> current which contains one shortest path, should add current to the 
// ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> path, which contains all shortest paths.
private void shortpath (int starti, int startj, int endi, int endj) {

        if (endi == starti && endj == startj) {
            current = new ArrayList<Cell>();
            current.add(new Cell(starti, startj));
            path1.add(current);
            return;
        }

        if (starti < endi) {
            shortpath (starti+1, startj, endi, endj);
            current.add(new Cell(starti, startj));
        }
        if (startj < endj) {    
            shortpath (starti, startj+1, endi, endj);
            current.add(new Cell(starti, startj));
        }
}
```

I do not really know how to do it better. 
Thanks in advance, 
Patrick

Comment: are there any obstacles on the way? I mean, does the algorithm need to eliminate some paths as they are unprocessable?

Comment: Pardon me if I am stating the obvious, but did you try Googling for _shortest path algorithm java_ ?

Comment: hello! yes i googled and found algorithms like BFS that give me one shortest path, but I did not quite figure out how to use it for finding and storing all shortest pathes.

Comment: yes there are obstacles in the way, and the aim is to find the path with the most obstacles and the path with the mimum amount of obstacles in it

Comment: While I am not very familiar with the algorithm, I do believe [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) should be the one you need.

Comment: If you're using BFS, you simply have to keep track of the depth of each node as it is enqueued and change the stopping criterion. Instead of stopping when the goal is reached the first time, record the depth **D** of the goal node when you first find it and continue until there are no nodes in the queue with a depth less than **D**.